# Why can't my library module find an import?

Tags: android, build.gradle, rxandroidble

I'm attempting to add a library module to an existing Android app.

Both modules have this in the dependencies section of their `build.gradle`:

`api "com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.5.0"`

Both have this import statement in the code:

`import com.polidea.rxandroidble2.RxBleClient;`

The app module has no compile errors, but in my library module I just get "cannot resolve symbol RxBleClient".

I've tried cleaning the project, invalidating the caches, nothing changes.

Comment: Could you post a result of a `./gradlew yourModule:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath`, for both the app and the library module?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?